# When was the -P option removed from perl?

Tags: perl

When was the `-P` option removed from perl?

> -P
>       causes your script to be run through the C preprocessor before compilation by Perl. (Because both comments and cpp directives begin
>   with the # character, you should avoid starting comments with any
>   words recognized by the C preprocessor such as `if`, `else`, or
>   `define`.)

I was just curious about when it was removed.

Comment: Someone put this on hold.  It's a question of fact, which was answered.  What is the "opinion" in question?

Comment: There's obviously no opinions involved in this question. What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-P` option was [deprecated in perl 5.10.0](https://metacpan.org/pod/perl5100delta#Use-of-P-is-deprecated) (December 2007) and [removed in perl 5.12.0](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5120delta.pod#Other-potentially-incompatible-changes) (April 2010).

Answer (score 4):

I often wonder about these questions when I'm writing about some Perl feature. Since I have most Perls installed, I can look at the right files from each version to discover when it disappears. Command-line switches show up in [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), so I can look back at the each perlrun until I find where the switch disappears.

I don't need to have all those Perls installed though. The [Perl source](https://github.com/Perl/perl5) is in GitHub, so you can look at the history of the perlrun file to find the change (and [here it is where you might start: "Remove the -P switch" - 4c84d7](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/commit/4c84d7f2a03f1d29578b3894e1b6863673b307fb#diff-aeeb32f8642bab9eafbc8cbd70157b04)).

The [perldelta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html) page also lists the changes for that version (and older versions' *perldelta* get moved to a versioned form, such as [perl5100delta](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html)). That's a bit more tedious to go through, especially since you can't bisect it.

Beyond that, Perl 5 Porters will deprecate a feature for two major versions (such as v5.28 and v5.30) before it's actually removed. Back in v5.10 [the policy](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpolicy.html) wasn't quite there yet, so that removal was a bit fast.

The curious thing now is that many things were deprecated in v5.000, and Perl 5 Porters are now removing those long-deprecated features.